# Web API: JSON Response not showing on Postman

Tags: c#, sql, .net, rest

I have developed web services for Registration. I successfully insert data into DB using the Post method in Postman. But on Postman the response body JSON not showing any response data just response code 200. I have tried to change "return Ok()" to "return Ok(user)" but turns out to be an error. Here is the image of Postman and my Controller code for Register.

[image]

```
public IHttpActionResult PostRegister(RegisterModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest("Invalid data.");
            }
            else
            {

                using (var user = new HISEntities1())
                {
                    user.WebUsers.Add(new WebUser()
                    {
                        Name=model.name,
                        Email=model.email,
                        Phone=model.phoneNumber,
                        Citizenship=model.nationality,
                        Num_ic=model.icNumber,
                        Gender=model.gender,
                        Apps_id=model.appsId

                    });

                    

                }

                return Ok();

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to return the object:

```
return Ok(user);
```

Comment: Please put this line of code inside the using block

Comment: okay i've done that. now i have this "The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'"

Comment: Can you please try:
return new OkObjectResult(user);